# can't < input type button /> dragged?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I just tried to dragg a button but i am not able to do that.

```
***CSS***
.aDiv_class {height:200px; width 150px; border: 1px solid gray; }

.dButton_class {height: 175px; width:125px; background: url('button.gif');  }

 ***HTML***
<div class="aDiv_Class"> 
  <input type="button" class="aButton_class" />
</div>

***JS***
 $(function() {

/*  $('.aDiv_Class').draggable();  // it works & a div attached with button can be dragged        */

    $('.aButton_class').draggable();   // I just wanted to drag this button but can't
});
```

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-ui@googlegroups.com/msg12224.html might help

Comment: ohh great RC. Thanks a ton. I hope this should work now.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.aButton_class').draggable();
```

you are missing the `.`

Comment: 4 seconds.  you beat me by 4 seconds!  :)

Comment: in the dimension if minutes we are equal `;)`

Comment: sorry, that is my typing mistake and in question only.

Answer (score 1):

there is a . missing

```
$('aButton_class').draggable();
```

should be

```
$('.aButton_class').draggable();
```

**edit**

it may be that the draggable plugin does not support dragging on buttons.

you could, i guess, try to remove the click even from the button but then it wouldn't be a button anymore.  and that, i think, is why draggable won't work on a button.

Comment: sorry, that is my typing mistake in question only.

Comment: there is no any click event on button

Comment: every button has a click event inherent in the control